# Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'size of BSON doc is 101 bytes, max is 0'

Tags: mongodb

I saw that there are few topics regarding the issue, but non of them solved my problem
I upgraded my mongo db to the newest version "MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5" and still got this serious error, that can be solved, this is a production server, so if someone can advice,i'll be glad more than happy

this is the stack trace:

```
 HP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'size of BSON doc is 101 bytes, max is 0' in /domain.com/app/vendors/mongo/MongoSessionHandler.php:51
Stack trace:
#0 /domain.com/vendors/mongo/MongoSessionHandler.php(51): MongoCollection->ensureIndex(Array)
#1 /domain.com/vendors/mongo/MongoSessionHandler.php(70): MongoSessionHandler->__construct()
#2 /domain.com/webroot/index.php(76): MongoSessionHandler::register()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /domain.com/vendors/mongo/MongoSessionHandler.php on line 51
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the driver are you using here? You can check this on the command line with `php --ri mongo` or you can check the output of `phpinfo()` in the browser. This used to be a problem but should not happen with 1.4.2. If it does, please file a bug at http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP

Comment: how can i check the driver version?